I can't change the data type in pandas_udf
I have this problem:
I need to take spark DataFrame data change the type of some columns and run scoring. here is my code
import lightgbm
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StringType

spark_dataset = spark.table(f'{tab_name}')

# pandas udf for prediction task
@F.pandas_udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def predict_udf(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist(), columns=model.feature_name_)
        
    for col in cat_columns:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    
    return pd.Series(model.predict_proba(df)[:, 1])

spark_dataset = spark_dataset.withColumn('features', F.array(model.feature_name_))

predict_test_df = spark_dataset.withColumn(
    'probability',
    predict_udf(F.col('features'))
)

predict_test_df.show()

As a result, I get a keyerror - there is no column from the list (the first in the list, most likely, and the rest). but I am exactly passing data that has all the necessary columns.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and is it possible to change the data type in this way?
I get the same error when using catboost, but I am trying to convert the data to str type.
I tried to change the feed format in pandas_udf, but to no avail. I think I lack knowledge here
